# Spring MVC: Not able to connect to Rest service

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Have written a `spring controller` Get method and trying to call that with postman but getting error

```
Could not get any response
There was an error connecting to https://localhost:8081/MyPortal/shared?video0=14&video1=15.
```

Even when I try to debug, the call is not going to the controller method. Not sure what is happening.

Here is the controller code:

```
@Controller
public class SharedLinkController {

@Autowired
VideoService videoService;

@RequestMapping("/shared")
public  ModelAndView getSharedVideo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        @RequestParam(value="video0", required=false) Long video0,
        @RequestParam(value="video1", required=false) Long video1,
        @RequestParam(value="video2", required=false) Long video2,
        @RequestParam(value="video3", required=false) Long video3){

    List<Lab> videos = new ArrayList<Lab>();

        // some processing with video0, video1 etc....

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("index");
    model.addObject("videos", videos);
    return model;

}

}
```

And this is how am trying to call the API:

```
https://localhost:8081/MyPortal/shared?video0=14&video1=15
```

Am not trying to make it a `RestController` as I need to redirect the call to a webpage. Is there anything wrong with the code?

Please suggest.

Comment: Where have you set mapping for /MyPortal?

Comment: "There was an error connecting to https", I would investigate https configuration (start with port number?), also include spring boot output.

Comment: you need to give some more information about how you setup your application. the controller looks fine

Comment: Its a web application running on Tomcat.

Comment: How do we specify `/MyPortal` ?

Comment: @Adya, if the path is wrong, then the error should be `404 not found`. It seems like server is not running or some port mismatch issue

Comment: What does tomcat .err and .out say?

Comment: This is a Spring Boot application so there is not .xml to define mappings.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a class that scans basepackages and registers your controller as a bean, like the following?

```
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages= "se.yourpackage.src")
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);

    }
```

Nevermind the RestController, but you need to add the requestmapping

```
@RequestMapping("/MyPortal")
public class SharedLinkController {
```

You might also need to add the path of the view files in your file called

> application.properties

for example:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/view/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

Comment: This is a Spring Boot application so there is not .xml to define mappings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the context to youe spring boot application, 
try setting

```
server.context-path=/MyPortal
```

This way you can define the root context to your application as

> http:localhost:8081/MyPortal/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check your url and your view name.

You try to connect url : connecting to http://localhost:8081/yourPortal/shared?video0=14&video1=15

```
@Controller
public class SharedLinkController {

   @Autowired
   VideoService videoService;

   @RequestMapping("/shared")
   public ModelAndView getSharedVideo(ModelAndView mav,
        @RequestParam(value="video0", required=false) Long video0,
        @RequestParam(value="video1", required=false) Long video1,
        @RequestParam(value="video2", required=false) Long video2,
        @RequestParam(value="video3", required=false) Long video3){

        List<Lab> videos = new ArrayList<Lab>();
        // ...

        mav.addObject("videos", videos);    
        mav.setViewName("index");

        return mav;
    }
}
```